# Deleted a file that was added to TortoiseSVN but wasn't committed

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN.

On my project I created a directory, put files on it, added everything to SVN source control but haven't committed it to the repository yet. It was looking like this:

```
/root_project_dir
-> .svn
-> dir1
  -> .svn
-> added_dir
  -> .svn
  -> subdir
```

But I mistakenly removed it with a regular Windows delete. Now, if I create the dir again, I can't add it to TortoiseSVN, it says:

"Directory '.../added_dir/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing. Please execute the "Cleanup" command.

Ok, but when I run the "Cleanup" command I get this:

".../added_dir" is not a working copy directory.

I tried removing the directory, doing cleanup, creating it again, but couldn't be successful.

How can I add this dir to versioning again?

Comment: I was under the impression added files just informed subversion that the files were in a state where they can be committed? It doesn't actually commit them to the repo?

Comment: @Kezzer they are commited only when you do a 'svn commit'. I did a 'svn add' on the files, but deleted them with "rm"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to revert the addition: right-click on "root_project_dir" folder (that was the parent folder, right?) and select "Revert".

Answer (score 2):

Do a `svn revert` on the directory you deleted.

Comment: The real solution would be reverting the addition of the top directory and then creating the directory and adding it to versioning again

Comment: svn revert added_dir should work fine. Afterwards the WC is in a usable state again and you can add the dir as usual

Answer (score 1):

Off top of my head

```
svn revert --force <dirname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the directory without using the SVN Add command. Then commit it.

Answer (score 0):

Do Right click on the added but not committed file and select option "Undo Add". Then you should perform Revert on your local repo directory or just delete the file.